# how to draw 3d text on QtOpenGLWindow?

Tags: qt, opengl, text, qt3d

I want to draw a number on 3 dimension axis.

For example, first grid is 10m, second grid is 20m etc.

I'd like to draw text on 3 dim(x,y,z), but it is very hard do drawing 3d text in `QtOpenGLWindow`.

I searched on google, but I didn't find a clear and compact function or API.

Do I have to implement my own function, or is there another way?

Comment: "*do I have to implement it??*" Yes. You're using a low-level rendering API, so you have to implement more specific rendering on top of it.

Comment: is there any high level rendering api for qt opengl? i dont need to understanding low level of opengl. but i cant find any high-level library.

Comment: Improved English.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any high level rendering api for qt opengl? i dont need to
>   understanding low level of opengl. but i cant find any high-level
>   library.

You are using the Qt Framework, which has the Qt3D module. It provides a high level api and it has a qextrudedtextgeometry. [see Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qextrudedtextgeometry.html#details) which does exactly what you want.

EDIT: there is an example in the sources, that uses several font types:
[distancefieldtext](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/5.12/tests/manual/distancefieldtext)
You can find it in the sources of your local installation too.
here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

It should be easy to compile and run it.